# Sum over row and column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's have for example the following dataframe:

```
   a  b  d  e
0  1  2  5  8
1  2  3  9  14
2  3  4  1  8
```

I would like to sum column d and e, and add those numbers together. Results in **sum = 45.** I couldn't find a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a list of the columns of interest to sub-select from your df, then call the attribute [`.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) to return a np array, you can then use [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to get the answer you desire:

```
In [49]:
np.sum(df[['d','e']].values)

Out[49]:
45
```

Or for a pure pandas way call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) twice:

```
In [50]:
df[['d','e']].sum().sum()

Out[50]:
45
```

Comment: The sum twice thing is what I always do in this situation.

Comment: @LondonRob it's because there is no `axis=None` in `df.sum` even if you passed this it will be set to column-wise (`axis=0`) I think whilst `np.sum` has default `axis=None` and this sums the entire array, probably worth a feature request on github

Answer (score 0):

if you have a dataset like this:

```
matrix = [
...     [1, 2, 3, 4],
...     [5, 6, 7, 8],
...     [9, 10, 11, 12],
... ]
```

then

```
>>> list(zip(*matrix))
```

gives you

```
[(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]
```

which in turn can be summed by index.

It's written well in the Python tutorial:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions